# wpf LostFocus event of Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is my xaml structure

```
<StackPanel>
  <m:TextBoxWithEllipsis IsEllipsisEnabled="True"
     Name="A"
     LostFocus="text_LostFocus"/>
  <m:TextBoxWithEllipsis IsEllipsisEnabled="True"
     Name="B"
     LostFocus="text_LostFocus"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**=> This structure can loop more. Such as:**

```
<StackPanel>
  <m:TextBoxWithEllipsis IsEllipsisEnabled="True"
     Name="A"
     LostFocus="text_LostFocus"/>
  <m:TextBoxWithEllipsis IsEllipsisEnabled="True"
     Name="B"
     LostFocus="text_LostFocus"/>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel>
  <m:TextBoxWithEllipsis IsEllipsisEnabled="True"
     Name="A"
     LostFocus="text_LostFocus"/>
  <m:TextBoxWithEllipsis IsEllipsisEnabled="True"
     Name="B"
     LostFocus="text_LostFocus"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**In .cs file, I define event lost focus as below**

```
private void text_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   TextBox textbox = ((TextBox)sender);
   if (textbox.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
   {
      System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result1 = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Empty string!", "Warning",
                 System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                textbox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { textbox.Focus(); }));
       return;
    }
    textbox.ScrollToHome();
}
```

**The problem**: If there are >= 2 textbox having value is empty ("").

1. I click first empty textbox => I don't enter any characters.
2. Then I click second empty textbox.

==> Program always show the message box => If I click OK button, It show another. It occur forever. I can't close the program.

**Question**: **If I have >= 2 empty textbox and I do same as problem above. How can I change the function `text_LostFocus` to solve the problem???**

**DEFAULT**:

- Value of these textbox is always empty (**DEFAULT**)
- Must use BeginInvoke => Because I want when user click to texbox, user must enter least a character.

Comment: Funny implementation XD When you have two textboxes, think of what's happening: 1. You enter the first tb 2. You don't enter anything and you click the second one 3. The lostfocus event of tb1 fires and it opens a dialog, and focuses on tb1 again 4. because tb1 got focus, tb2's lostfocus event fires and it does the same, returning focus to tb2 and going on in an infinite loop.

Comment: Also - no need for `BeginInvoke`. You are already on the UI thread.

Comment: I thought this is WPF an not WinForms, this `System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult` can be easily replaced with `System.Windows.MessageBox`!

Comment: @GSP, what if you try reacting on `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus`? AFAIK, it occurs even before the other tb gets focus.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.previewlostkeyboardfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): If the `PreviewGotKeyboardFocus` event or the `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus` event is handled, keyboard focus does not change.

Comment: Thanks all. @Moti Azu **Must use BeginInvoke => Because I want when user click to texbox, user must enter least a character.**. If I click on first textbox and I click out of it (not click on second textbox), BeginInvoke will help me to focus on first textbox for user enter at least on character.

Comment: I would advise against showing a pop-up whenever someone leaves a textbox without entering data: it is really annoying. Mark it visually (e.g. a red cross besides it); also don't enable the submit-button until the minimum requirements are met.

Comment: @BCdotNET My these textboxes will generate when user click button add. So user must enter at least one character for this textbox to continue. This is condition.

Comment: @GSP `BeginInvoke` doesn't do what you say, it just runs code on a specific dispatcher. `textbox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { textbox.Focus(); }));` should be replaced with `textbox.Focus();`

Comment: @Moti Azu If I remove BeginInvoke, the message box shows only once. So User can leave this textbox while textbox.text is empty.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't use a MessageBox if I were you.
WPF has a very good "binding validation framework" (take a [look here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation) for a very good tutorial).
Otherwise I would create a "warning" label located close each textbox:

```
<StackPanel>
  <m:TextBoxWithEllipsis IsEllipsisEnabled="True"
     Name="A"
     LostFocus="text_LostFocus"/>
  <TextBlock Name="AWarning" Foreground="Red" />
  <m:TextBoxWithEllipsis IsEllipsisEnabled="True"
     Name="B"
     LostFocus="text_LostFocus"/>
  <TextBlock Name="BWarning" Foreground="Red" />
</StackPanel>
```

Then in the code-behind:

```
private void text_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = ((TextBox)sender);
    TextBlock textBlock = FindName(String.Concat(textBox.Name, "Warning")) as TextBlock;
    textBlock.Text = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text) ? "Empty string!" : String.Empty;
}
```