# How can I trigger when I leave the ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

so Ive got an DataGrid and in that i got a **DataGridTemplateColumn**. In that template Column i placed an ComboBox in it. The ComboBox got his Data from my ObservableCollections from my ViewModel. So that my Code look like that now:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="cbStatus"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ocLieferumfangStati, ElementName=vmLieferumfang}"
                                Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                          DisplayMemberPath="Beschreibung"
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding Status}"
                                          SelectedValuePath="Status" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But what I want to do now is, to have an Event what triggering when I leave the ComboBox. Something like the DataGrid event **CellEditEnding**.

What I already tried is in my MVVM this:

```
ocLieferumfangStati.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ADD");
            }
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Move");
            }
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Remove");
            }
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Replace");
            }
        };
```

But there only the **Remove Action** triggerd.

I can not write in the ComboBox, I can only choose the Items that are in the ComboBox. So how can I give out an MessageBox when I'm leaving the ComboBox? So that when I click out of the ComboBox an MessageBox is triggering.

Comment: By "leave" you mean "lose focus"? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820278/wpf-lostfocus-event-of-textbox

Comment: I mean when I tap out of the ComboBox.

Comment: Yes, but "tap out" isn't an event. There are a number of more specific events that get triggered when you perform such an action.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for SelectionChanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus` or `LostKeyboardFocus`,
So here check [Detect when a ListBoxItem is in the SelectedUnfocused state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108949/detect-when-a-listboxitem-is-in-the-selectedunfocused-state)
and [WPF Combobox lostfocus event become an Infinite lopp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660935/wpf-combobox-lostfocus-event-become-an-infinite-lopp)

Comment: that got triggerd when I try to open the ComboBox